# AWS Elastic Transcoder forces rotation on vertical videos

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I've been using the transcoder for a long time via AWS javascript API to create HLS versions of vertical videos (uploaded from mobile phones). So far "rotation: auto" perfectly handled them and kept them in their vertical position (height 640, width 360 and the video is in its original orientation).

Since yesterday (without changing anything on my end), video contents suddenly get rotated to 90 degrees and their content is stretched. The video resolution is still vertical but the content itself is rotated and stretched.

I tried creating a job from the console and ended with the same result.

Here is the command from my node JS code:

```
var params = {
  PipelineId : "<id>",
  Input : {
    Key: "<key>",
    FrameRate : "auto",
    AspectRatio : "auto",
    Interlaced : "auto",
    Container : "auto",
    Resoultion : "auto"
  },
  OutputKeyPrefix : "<prefix>",
  Outputs : [ 
  {
    PresetId : "1351620000001-200020",
    Key : "hls150",
    ThumbnailPattern : "",
    Rotate : "auto",
    SegmentDuration : "10.0"
  }, 
  {
    PresetId : "1351620000001-200030",
    Key : "hls100",
    Rotate : "auto",
    SegmentDuration : "10.0"
  }, 
  {
    PresetId : "1351620000001-200040",
    Key : "hls060",
    ThumbnailPattern : "",
    Rotate : "auto",
    SegmentDuration : "10.0"
  }],
  Playlists : [ {
    Name : "<name>",
    Format : "HLSv3",
    OutputKeys :   [ "hls060", "hls100", "hls150" ] 
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed by the AWS team.

Everything is back to normal.